# Umlauts SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, json, diacritics, sql-server-2019

I am using SQL Server 2019 and I have a nested json which is imported in this table.
In this json file I have some German characters (umlauts) and when I read the json in query the following character is replaced. ü=AL

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\test.json', SINGLE_CLOB) 
AS j

Select @JSON collate Latin1_General_CI_A
```

This json is encoded with UTF-8 and SQL Server 2019 has the UTF-8 encoding. How can I read the characters correctly?

Comment: Try specifing the Code Page value, for UTF-8 that's `65001`: [Specifying a format file and code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-specifying-a-format-file-and-code-page)

Comment: On a different note, `Latin1_General_CI_A` isn't a valid collation.

Comment: "collate Latin1_General_CI_AS" I missed the last letter

Comment: Did specifying the code page work?

Comment: @Larnu (BULK 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\client.json' ,  CODEPAGE = '65001', SINGLE_CLOB)  I've added like this and I have the same issue..

Comment: This implies that the file isn't actually UTF-8 then.

Comment: @Larnu I've opened the json in notepad++ and the encoding selected is UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding of the source file `test.json` to UTF-16 (or to USC-2 BE BOM in Notepad++) and use the `SINGLE_NCLOB` option.

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET 
(BULK 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\test.json', SINGLE_NCLOB) 
AS j

Select @JSON
```